# Региональное министерство культуры

Tags: названия, прописная, строчная

Кто знает, как следует писать региональное министерство культуры (и прочие названия учреждений местного значения) - со строчной "министерство" или с прописной? Почему?

Answer (score 2):

С прописной буквы пишут *имена собственные в названиях федеральных органов исполнительной власти*, например, *Министерство иностранных дел Российской Федерации* ([ссылка](http://www.profiz.ru/sr/7_2008/pravila_napisania_oficial/)).

> Слова *министерство*, служба, агентство пишутся со строчной буквы во множественном числе и не в качестве имен собственных: Предложить агентству рассмотреть вопрос о…; По согласованию с министерствами…

В Вашем случае *"региональное министерство культуры"* надо писать с маленькой буквы. Оно не является именем собственным, поскольку оно местного, а не государственного значения.